# Google Maps v2 loading in a Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs, android-fragments

I have a tab and I would like load a map in a fragment of this tab, but I have some errors that I can´t solve.

this is in my

```
MainActivity extends FragmentActivity

 private void initViewPager() {
//      SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
//      mMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
//              .findFragmentById());
        // 0. creamos una lista de fragment (vistas)
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        //fragments.add(new TabChat());
        fragments.add(new TabMapa());
        //fragments.add(new TabInformacion());

        // 1. iniciamos el viewpager
        this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // 2. creamos el adapter, que tambien implementara onPageChangeListener
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                fragments);

        // 3. suscribimos adapter y listener del viewpager
        this.mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
    }
```

TabMapa

```
public class TabMapa extends Fragment {
private GoogleMap gmap;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_mapa);
    initGMap();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_mapa,
            container, false);
    initGMap();
    return myFragmentView;
}
private void initGMap() {
    // obtenemos el mapa desde el fragment
    gmap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.gmap)).getMap();
}
  }
```

xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Mapa" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/gmap"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the  error is in getSupportFragmentManager(), TabMap should extends FragmentActivity for solve it, but if I extends from FragmentActivity I have an error when I load the Fragment, here fragments.add(new TabMapa());

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this ?

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Before you do this Right click project->properties->buildpath->java build path -> libraries .. then click on add external jars

the go to

**user\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v4**

and select **android-support-v4.jar**

Comment: yes I did it, the problem is that the Tab, need a Fragment and the Map need a FragmentActivity, I know that I can solve it with SupportMapFragment but I dont know how I have to use it and where I have to put it